# React native expo camera "no access to camera" error

Tags: react-native, expo

I have installed the expo camera tool with npm.

I run this code and it works on Snack :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";

export default function Scanner() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        onBarCodeScanned={console.log}
        barCodeScannerSettings={{
          barCodeTypes: [BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr],
        }}
      />
      {scanned && (
        <Button title={"Tap to Scan Again"} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

But in localhost I have the message "no access to camera"and I have no popup asking for access.

I am a complete beginner with react native and I can't figure out how to fix this ^^.

EDIT : I'm running it on web

Comment: it's because you declined the access for first time, what you have to do id uninstall expo go and install it again, and make sure to allow camera to be used

Comment: @chikabala when I run npm install -g expo-cli, it does'nt ask me for permission, do I need to do something else ?

Comment: `npm install -g expo-cli` is for installing expo in your machine (laptop/pc) , what i told you to do is to uninstall expo go the mobile application

Comment: @chikabala I am not able to try it on phone, when I do so, the app doesn't load after scanning the expo QR code. So I would like to try it on web.